# Vue: How to bind property dynamically to a new DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Say, I have a component with the following template:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Then somehow I call the code that appends a new element to it (using jQuery for now):

```
$('#root').append('<div id="a1" v-bind:styles="styles.a1"></div>')
```

where "styles.a1" is just an object from component's data:

```
data() {
   return {
      styles: { a1: {color: 'red'} }
   };
}
```

I suppose the newborn element's binding will not work because Vue doesn't know anything about this new element and its binding.

But maybe there is **some** way to implement the desired logic?

PS I know that Vue's nature is to manipulate with data, not DOM but here is the situation I have to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a style without a value first,

```
data() {
   return {
      styles: { a1: '' }
   };
}
```

then you can add data into that from an event via normal JS. (JQuery isn't even necessary here).

```
methods: {
   quack() {
        this.styles.a1 = { color: red }
    }
}
```

Edit: I got it wrong. Seems Vue does not detect newly added elements after being mounted. So what you can do is mount the Vue instance after the appended elements are added or to re-render the whole instance with `forceUpdate` . (The latter will re-render the whole instance so I recommend breaking down into multiple Vue instances for the sake of performance)

[ForceUpdate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately your answer is not what I'm asking about. My question is how to create a new element, add it to DOM (or somehow bind else) and bind some data to it - all programmatically. The style object is only for the example.

Comment: Ah, got it wrong. Sorry. Yes you can! You just need to remount the instance after appending it since Vue doesn't detect them though. ^^ Here's more info! Wait, got the wrong link. A minute

Comment: Updated. Hope that's the answer you want

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I want but I will consider this feature (to update the whole instance).

Comment: or you can make multiple Vue instances and just update the appended instance so it wouldn't re-render the whole page ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vue components you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM.

- You should either use template logic for that.

  ```html
     <template v-if="someCondition">
         <div id="a1" v-bind:styles="styles.a1"></div>
     </template>
  ```
- Wrap non Vue code inside it's own Vue component.

  ```js
  Vue.component('date-picker', {
    template: '<input/>',
    mounted: function() {
      $(this.$el).datepicker();
    },
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      $(this.$el).datepicker('hide').datepicker('destroy');
    }
  });
  ```

  https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/
- Use a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

  ```js
  Vue.directive('demo', {
      bind: function () {
          $(this.el).css({color:'#fff', backgroundColor:this.arg});
      },
      update: function (value) {
          $(this.el).html(
              'argument - ' + this.arg + '!<br>' +
              'key - ' + this.key + '<br>' +
              'value - ' + value);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: I would like NOT to use DOM manipulation but the problem is template is loaded dynamically (and it can be anything), secondly I HAVE to add new elements. Please point me how to avoid manipulation DOM in this case.

Comment: In this case you should use string templates, compiled templates will not work.

Comment: Or if you must you can add more html using the `v-html` but you cannot add directives to it

Comment: Can you add more information on using string templates, how it would help?

Comment: I can't use any template logic because in my case template can be anything. Another thing is I have to add new elements only after the template is mounted and rendered. And I don't see how a custom directive would help if I don't know in advance what will be a new element.

Comment: If you manipulate the DOM, the vue runtime may decide to re-render the whole view at any time, destroying all the changes you made. So you have to attach your mutations to the vue life cycles, either through components life cycle or directives, which is the recommended way of having access to the raw DOM elements.

Comment: @mimic see how the last example I gave uses jquery to inject custom html to a node.

Comment: Vitim.us, do you mean the example with directive "demo"? Can you please explain how I would use it?